# Cocoa modal window with a pointed top border

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, nswindow

I'm not sure what you call this window/view but recently I've seen an increase in this type of window/view in Cocoa applications. The window/view itself is most like a HUD window, but with a pointed top border.

The type of window/view I'm talking about can be seen here. http://www.finaltouchapp.com/

What is this called? Is it something built into Cocoa, or is it custom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lion introduces `NSPopover`, which has a HUD style (`NSPopoverAppearanceMinimal`). For earlier systems, [`MAAttachedWindow`](http://mattgemmell.com/source/index.html#maattachedwindow) is popular.